# Performing Weighted Flow Accumulation in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, dem, hydrology, flow-accumulation, taudem

I would like to calculate a weighted flow accumulation raster with GRASS. I have a DEM and a rainfall raster. I am looking to calculate the rainfall accumulated downstream. Basically, it is similar in the way that is calculated Flow Accumulation, but instead of sum cells with value 1, I would like to sum values from the rainfall raster.

It seems very easy in ArcGIS Desktop, but can I do it with GRASS?

Answer (score 3):

I think that I found a solution for this. The *r.watersheds* function that calculates flow accumulation, have a parameter (*flow*) to integrate a raster indicating values to sum.

> Parameter:
>   **flow**=name
>   Name of input raster representing amount of overland flow per cell
>
> Raster **flow** map specifies amount of overland flow per cell. This map
>   indicates the amount of overland flow units that each cell will
>   contribute to the watershed basin model. Overland flow units represent
>   the amount of overland flow each cell contributes to surface flow. If
>   omitted, a value of one (1) is assumed.

Source: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.watershed.html

Comment: I think you found the right use of the parameter, beacuase the parameter name is quite wrong and a source of misleading. Certainly it is not a way to add flow, but volume, or a sort of. Could you share an example of its use? Assuming the rainfall is in mm, the cellsize is required somewhere and I think the final output should be in m^3 (or Hm^3)

Answer (score 1):

[`r.watershed`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/r.watershed.html) assumes a flow of 1 when the `flow` parameter is omitted, resulting in the number of accumulated upstream raster cells. So the unit of the final output will be the same as that of the `flow` raster map. For example, depth `flow` results in depth output; volume `flow` results in volume output.